# How do I print the remaining cards of the deck? (Python)

Tags: python, blackjack

I followed a tutorial to code blackjack in python. It generates a deck, and plays one round of blackjack, then ends the program. Once the player and the dealer have received all of their cards, and the outcome is declared, I want to print all of the remaining cards in the deck to verify it is working properly. This way I can move on to playing with more than one deck confidently.

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,value,suit):
        self.cost = value
        self.value = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'][value-1]
        self.suit = '♥♦♣♠'[suit]

    def price(self):
        if self.cost >= 10:
            return 10
        elif self.cost == 1:
            return 11
        return self.cost
    
    def show(self):
        print('_________')
        print(f'| {self.value:<2}    |')
        print('|       |')
        print(f'|   {self.suit}   |')
        print('|       |')
        print(f'|    {self.value:>2} |')
        print('_________')




import random
from card import Card

class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []

    def generate(self):
        for i in range(1, 14):
            for j in range(4):
                self.cards.append(Card(i, j))

    def draw(self, iteration):
        cards = []
        for i in range(iteration):
            card = random.choice(self.cards)
            self.cards.remove(card)
            cards.append(card)
        return cards
    
    def count(self):
        return len(self.cards)
    
    def remaining(self):





from deck import Deck

class Player:
    def __init__(self, isDealer, deck):
        self.cards = []
        self.isDealer = isDealer
        self.deck = deck
        self.score = 0

    def hit(self):
        self.cards.extend(self.deck.draw(1))
        self.check_score()
        if self.score > 21: #Useless
            return 1
        return 0
    
    def deal(self):
        self.cards.extend(self.deck.draw(1))
        self.check_score()
        if self.score == 21: #Useless
            return 1
        return 0
    
    def check_score(self):
        a_counter = 0
        self.score = 0
        for card in self.cards:
            if card.price() == 11:
                a_counter += 1
            self.score += card.price()

        while a_counter != 0 and self.score > 21:
            a_counter -= 1
            self.score -= 10
        return self.score
    
    def show(self):
        if self.isDealer:
            print("Dealer's Cards")

            for i in self.cards:
                i.show()

            print("Score: " + str(self.score))

        elif not self.isDealer:
            print("Players Cards")

            for i in self.cards:
                i.show()

            print("Score: " + str(self.score))




from deck import Deck
from player import Player

class Blackjack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = Deck()
        self.deck.generate()
        self.player = Player(False, self.deck)
        self.dealer = Player(True, self.deck)

    def play(self):
        self.player.deal()
        self.dealer.deal()
        self.player.hit()

        self.dealer.show()

        if self.dealer.check_score() == 11: #Don't forget about chips
            print("Insurance?")

        self.dealer.hit()

        if self.player.check_score() == 21:
            p_status = 1
        else:
            p_status = 0
        if self.dealer.check_score() == 21:
            d_status = 1
        else:
            d_status = 0

        self.player.show()

        if p_status == 1:
            print("Player got Blackjack! Congrats!")
            if d_status == 1:
                self.dealer.show()
                print("Dealer and Player got Blackjack! It's a push. (Tie)") #Won't work since dealer only has one card
            return 1
        
        cmd = ""
        while cmd != "Stand":
            bust = 0
            cmd = input("Hit or Stand? ")

            if cmd == "Hit":
                bust = self.player.hit()
                self.player.show()

            if bust == 1:
                print("Player busted. Good Game!")
                return 1
        print("\n")
        self.dealer.show()
        if d_status == 1:
            print("Dealer got Blackjack! Better luck next time!")
            return 1
        
        while self.dealer.check_score() < 17:
            if self.dealer.hit() == 1:
                self.dealer.show()
                print("Dealer busted. Congrats!")
                return 1
            self.dealer.show()

        if self.dealer.check_score() == self.player.check_score():
            print("It's a Push (Tie). Better luck next time!")
        elif self.dealer.check_score() > self.player.check_score():
            print("Dealer wins. Good Game!")
        elif self.dealer.check_score() < self.player.check_score():
            print("Player wins. Congradulations!")

        self.deck.remaining()

b = Blackjack()
b.play()
```

Comment: Implement `def remaining(self):` loop over `self.cards` and print them. You already have so many loops that it looks like you understood the concept.

Comment: What have you tried? You look like a beginner and IMO it will be more valuable for you to find it yourself. As a hint, where is the deck card stored? Look at the draw method.

Comment: `print(self.deck.cards)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple for loop will do the trick. All the other code in the deck class looks like it properly removes a card from the list.
So:

```
def remaining(self):
   print("Remaining cards in deck":)
   for card in self.cards:
      print(card)
```

Printing out the entire list as a whole is also a possibility.

```
print(self.cards)
```

In any case:
Just make sure that the card class has a `__str__()` method.

```
def __str__(self):
   return self.suit + self.value
```

This function gets called whenever a string representation of the class instance is requested. So, it can be used to return a string of what that representation must be.

Comment: "a string representation of the class" should be "a string representation of an instance of the class".

Comment: Adjusted the issue